# Is it possible to set DNS records in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, dns

I've discovered a couple Node.js modules that allow for checking DNS records for domains, but none that allow for *changing and setting* DNS records to update domains.

Is what I'm asking even possible? I'm just looking for a step in the right direction.

I am using DNS Made Easy for my DNS servers, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think it really depends on the DNS server you're using.  There are some standardized ways to update DNS servers - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS, or if you're using a service like afraid.org, then they have a REST-ish/HTTP endpoint you can call to update DNS records.  There's no reason you couldn't initiate that call from node.js.  That said - if you're trying to do real DDNS, you might have to implement a more tricky protocol to get it to happen.  Some DNS servers just read text files from the disk, so you could also build something that updates those files and the domain serial number and reloads the server when an update occurs.  TL;DR: it's possible, but you might have to implement some tricky stuff to get it to work.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using DNS Made Easy for my DNS servers. I would like my users to be able to edit the DNS for their domains. I've never heard of `afraid.org`, thanks for sharing! Maybe I can get some ideas from them.

Comment: Looks like they have a REST API.  Should be plain sailing: https://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/pdf/API-Docv2.pdf